# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^\sqrt{n}}{c^n}$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

How could I show that the following limit tends to $0$? The constant $c$ can take any value strictly greater than $1.$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{e^\sqrt{n}}{c^n}$$

I'm having trouble on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Sketch a graph of the logarithm of your ratio on the vertical axis and $\sqrt n$ on the horizontal axis.  You will meet an old friend.

Comment: The limit is equal to zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your limit can be write as $\lim e^{\sqrt{n}-log(c)n}$, and $\lim (\sqrt{n}-log(c)n)=  -\infty$, so $\lim e^{\sqrt{n}-log(c)n}=0$ (or you can make a rigorous proof).